# Ask Firebase for changes compared to last time the app was running

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

*Shortly:* In order to limit the quantity of documents that are returned by Firebase, I wonder if it is possible to request the last updated documents compared to the ones in cache ?

---

I currently request all the collection as a Stream and listen on updates.

```
Firestore.instance.collection(COLLECTION).snapshots().listen((snapshot) {
  snapshot.documentChanges.forEach((doc) {
    // ...
  });
});
```

Unfortunately, I have a big collection (> 1000 documents) so everytime the application start, a single user cost me a lot because more than 1000 documents are returned. Before doing it in my way like add a "updatedAt" column , "orderBy" it and try other things like that, I think that is must exist a simplier manner of doing it.

So is there a way to tell Firebase to only return the updated documents since the last time (based on the ones which are in the cache for example) ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is only possible if you have some indication of what is in the cache/when a document was last updated. Otherwise it'd require Firestore to read each document to check whether it was modified, which will incur the exact cost that you're trying to avoid.

So you'll need to have a timestamp field in each document that indicates when it was last updated, and then query only documents that were updated since you last synchronized. Firestore doesn't keep such information automatically, so you'll have to add/track it yourself.

It is definitely possible, but you'll have to wonder whether this is the right use of Firestore. The local cache is meant to be just that: a cache, and not a full fledged database. While it can perform all the queries that the server can, query performance on the local cache *does* deteriorate with the cache size, unlike the performance of queries on the server.

Typically you'll get the best ROI if you read the data that you're showing to the user, instead of trying to get large swaths of data in the local cache.

Answer (score 0):

The only way is to add a field `updated` and then query:

```
Firestore.instance.collection("collectionName").where("updated", isEqualTo : true).getDocuments().then((querySnapshot) {
    querySnapshot.documents.forEach((result) {
      print(result.data);
    });
  });
```